# JCK Editor Cleans the Code upon save

Tags: joomla3.0

I am using JCK Editor in Joomla 3 but when i try to put this code  in article and
press save, it cleans up the code and i only get nothing except the word 'Home'
Please help as possible

Thanking you in anticipation

```
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring Joomla's editor. You might ask on [joomla.se] but check their help centre first.

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly configure Joomla from stripping away your HTML tags by configuring your user groups ‘Filter Type’ to: ‘No Filtering’ or to your own preference for the respective Filter Groups.

By default JCK will strip the Glyphicons.

You can also set Global Config - Editor to 'none' which will do the same thing.

Personally I use JCE Editor which I find to be more capable.